# How to remove the "\r\t\t" escape characters from XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

Reading outer Xml from an `XmlReader`, how do I remove whitespaces("\n\t\t") in my output?

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new FileStream(archivePath, FileMode.Open)))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (reader.Depth == 1)
            {
                var xe = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                XElement.Parse(xe.ToString(), LoadOptions.None);

                var reader2 = xe.CreateReader();
                reader2.MoveToContent();
                var content = reader2.ReadOuterXml(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Um...[`.Trim();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: Seems like there ought to be a more elegant solution than trimming.  Check out the XmlReaderSettings class, IgnoreWhitespace property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using XmlReaderSettings:

```
var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    IgnoreWhitespace = true,
};

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new FileStream(archivePath, FileMode.Open), readerSettings))
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string.Replace(@"\n\t\t", "");

Comment: As you're using a verbatim string, it won't replace whitespaces the OP wants to remove...

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

edit: Not a function; I have no idea what was going through my head.

```
reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
```